# How to change CFAttributedString's string but not attributes?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, core-foundation

Now I have a CFAttributedString, and the attribute is not identical in the whole string, for example, index 0-2 are blue and 3-5 are black, I want to change the text of it, but don't alter the attributes, **I want to copy the string, but I don't always know when the attributes start being different, CFAttributedStringGetAttributes can only specify one location to get the attributes,** is there any good method to copy the attributes respectively in the string? or can I just change the string but not attributes?

Comment: Is there some good reason why we can't use NSAttributedString here? It is a _lot_ easier to work with.

Comment: If NSAttributedString can do that, then how to implement it? like  I  change the CFAttributedString to NSAttributedString, and change the string, then back to CFXXXString without losing attributes?

Comment: What I'm asking is why you are using CFAttributedString at all. Note that you do not need to "change" a CFAttributedString to an NSAttributedString. They are the same thing ("toll-free bridged").

Comment: I want to overwrite a method to filter some text, the argument is CFAttributedString, and I only want to change the string of it then return the CFAttributedString, just  like I haven't changed anything.

Comment: But that doesn't mean we have to do it in the CF world. It is much easier in the NS world, and they are toll-free bridged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not explained why we have to do this in the CFAttributedString world, and I certainly can't think of a reason to do so, so here's a basic outline of how to do it in the NSAttributedString world. Basically, you just cycle through the attributes of the first string and assign them to the second string:

```
// index 0-2 are blue and 3-5 are black

let s = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "blublack", attributes: [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()
])
s.addAttributes(
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()], 
    range: NSMakeRange(0,3)
)

// I want to change the text of it, 
// but don't alter the attributes

let s2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "12345678")
s.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSMakeRange(0,s.length), options: nil, usingBlock: {
    d,r,_ in
    s2.addAttributes(d, range: r)
})
```

That gives the desired result. Of course you also have to ask yourself what to do if the strings are of different lengths, but you didn't provide any spec for that in your question, so dealing with that issue is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining clearly, what I want at last is get a CFAttributedString with only changing the string, now I know I can use the method in  NSMutableAttributedString to do that, then toll-free back to CF, that's a common way to alter the CF object, I should read the document carefully, thanks for your guide!